# Laravel route not defined

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to send a contact form with Laravel
So in the top of my contact form I have this

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'contact', 'name'=>"sentMessage", 'id'=>"contactForm"])}}
```

I have routes for contact page like this

```
Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::post('/contact','EmailController@test');
```

in my EmailController file I have something like this

```
public function test()
{
    return View::make('thanks-for-contact');
}
```

Whenever I open my contact page I get this error message

```
Route [contact] not defined
```

Comment: instead of `'action'` use `'url' => 'contact'`

Answer (score 3):

when you use the attribute action you provide it a method in your controller like so :

```
// an example from Laravel's manual
Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method'))
```

maybe a better solution with be to use named routes, which will save you a lot of time if you ever wanted to change your URL.

```
Route::get('/contact', array('as' => 'contact.index', 'uses' => 'PagesController@contact'));
Route::post('/contact', array('as' => 'contact.send', 'uses' => 'EmailController@test'));
```

then your form will look something like this :

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'contact.send', 'name'=>"sentMessage", 'id'=>"contactForm")) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'action' in your opening tags, so its trying to go to a controller by that name. Try using 'url' => 'contact'.